# Please advice D3.js for CSV data import

Tags: d3.js

I am trying to import CSV data with using D3.js.

```
var englishArray="";
d3.csv("data.csv",
    function(d) {
        return [d.value]
    },
    function(error, data) {
var englishArray =data;            
console.log(data);
    }
);
```

I want to get data from CSV file, which is

```
value
I am Kevin.
I am cute.
I am OK.
```

BY the way, original data in js file is

```
var englishArray =[ "I am Kevin."," I am cute.","I am OK."];
```

I want to put all value data into englishArray but 
it does not work.
I am appreciate if you advise me what the problems are.
Thanks.

Comment: You can not return values from an async function like this. Put your logic inside the callback instead.

Comment: Are you aware that the csv file will not be read from your file system but transferred over a HTTP connection? Did you set up a server to send the .csv file? Also, in case of an HTTP error the data may be empty and englishArray will be undefined.

Comment: Thank you. Data was uploaded the server. No problem. var englishArray =data;   should be moved just after return [d.value]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/CSV) is the example which describe how to import csv file in d3.js.

CSV File

```
Year,Make,Model,Length
1997,Ford,E350,2.34
2000,Mercury,Cougar,2.38
```

JavaScript Array is

```
[
  {"Year": "1997", "Make": "Ford", "Model": "E350", "Length": "2.34"},
  {"Year": "2000", "Make": "Mercury", "Model": "Cougar", "Length": "2.38"}
]
```

Code to import CSV data using d3.js

```
d3.csv("example.csv", function(d) {
  return {
    year: new Date(+d.Year, 0, 1), // convert "Year" column to Date
    make: d.Make,
    model: d.Model,
    length: +d.Length // convert "Length" column to number
  };
}, function(error, rows) {
  console.log(rows);
});
```