# Please advice D3.js for CSV data import(Part2)

Tags: d3.js

I would like to ask more about the issue for
[Please advice D3.js for CSV data import](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32068968/please-advice-d3-js-for-csv-data-import?noredirect=1#comment52036627_32068968)

I tried to modify the code, but it may still not work.
Thank you for your advice.

```
var englishArray="";
d3.csv("data.csv",function(d) {
    return [d.value];
    var englishArray = data;  
}, function(error, data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

Comment: @KevinSuzuki This and your previous question are not clear -- please state what you are trying to do, what is the expected outcome, what is the actual outcome. "It may still not work" is meaningless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to understand that the d3.csv function is asynchronous, so you have to use the data only in that function.

So, in your code:

1. What you return in the success callback won't be seen or used anywhere
2. You cannot set `englishArray` after returning
3. You should use `data` inside of the callback instead of setting an outer variable since the function is not blocking.